# In magento 2.3 I have changed the theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In **Magento 2.3** I have installed the **theme porto** and it is successfully installed
I already tried and run the following commands:

> setup:upgrade
>   static-content:deploy

Every thing is done and fine.

Theme is activated every page is working on porto theme but the homepage is using luma theme what could be the possible reasons let me know I will try it that is the weird thing I have ever seen in **Magento 2** .

I need some suggestions thanks

Comment: did you try to check your store view configuration? maybe it is not correctly set to your theme

Comment: Remove var/view_preprocessed folder and check

Answer (score 0):

I think for your Home Page Theme set as Luma

Below steps you can follow:

1. Goto `Admin >Content > Pages`
2. Click yours `Home Page` to edit
3. Inside `Custom Design Update` set the new Theme you have installed.
4. Clear Cache

Answer (score 0):

It can be a system glitch. Usually, it doesn’t happen, to change the theme you can follow these steps and it will resolve the home page issue you are facing.

In admin Go to Content > Design> Configuration

Click on Edit

On the Default Theme tab, Apply Theme drop down

Select Newly Created Theme

Click on Save Configuration

Clear the Cache

Reload the Storefront page

Follow these steps again and it will enable you to apply a new theme.